# How can I show my personal stuff from Facebook in my website?

Tags: php, python, facebook, web

I searched in Stack Overflow, Google, etc, but I can't figure out how to show my stuff from my Facebook on my website. I tried some solutions and each one prompted the login dialog and visitors had to log in and accept my application (I've created one to test).

Many answers here were too generic, I didn't understand them that is why I'm asking.

I want something that would let my website "log in" to Facebook and show my status or photos to visitors without them needing to accept an app or log in into Facebook with their account.

I tried a facebook-php-sdk example with my AppID and AppSecret and it asked me to log in.
Also, github.com/facebook doesn't have an SDK for Python similar to facebook-php-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a script (eg. using the FB PHP SDK) that uses a [long-lived access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/) to fetch your FB data and then store the data in your backend database (or other store for your website). To Facebook, your script will look like an app and your machine will be the only 'user' of that app.  Note, long-lived access tokens are good for 60 days max.  You could also try using an [App Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/) to fetch basic info.  App Access Tokens don't expire.

Comment: Hi Donn Lee, thank you for answering, I am confused.
I tried fb php sdk, I get the access token like this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/ but I tried to use that token with fb php sdk and I get "not connected", but I tried the same code with the access token from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/APP_ID/ and works, but I don't know how to get that token with php, also I don't know if that token is user token or app toke or what..

Comment: Try using a user access token instead of a page access token. Make a short html page with $facebook->getLoginUrl(), auth the app, and error_log() the user access token with $facebook->getAccessToken().  And then test the access token in the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).  See also [Extending Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for since you posted this with the php and python tag, but it might solve your problem.

If you're website is powered by the wordpress engine you can use If-this-then-that : https://ifttt.com/

It basically allows you to create "recipes" with something like:
if new status on Facebook then create post on wordpress

The post will not require others to log in to Facebook.

This is without writing a single line of code only a couple of mouse clicks. So I'm not sure if this satisfies your needs.

Comment: Hi Uirri, thank you for the advice, but I am developing the website!